# Enable feature access editing in Arcgis Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, wfs, feature-service

I had published a WFS/Feature Access service via ArcMap. But I can't edit layers (change geometry or data fields). Such settings in properties window are disabled (see an image). How to enable editing these layers?

[image: Service Editor]
[image: start_editing]

Answer (score 1):

to add on what others have said, you need to be sure the dataset in the service has editor tracking enabled, global ids, and registered as versioned. You can do all of this via Arc Catalog, and to be safe overwrite the existing service once this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WFS section / tab on the left. You should have a check box that enables transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In ArcCatalog 'Register as versioned' layers you want to edit. Check the box - move edits to geodatabase.